# Relating the values one table to another table

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have two tables. One is named usertbl with columns user_id, user_name, and acct_status. possible values for acct_status values are 0, 1, 2, 3. Another table named accountstatustbl has the following columns - acct_status, and acct_status_desc, with values when acct_status = 0, acct_status_desc = enrolled, 1 = active, 2 = inactive, and 3 = deactivated. Now, how should I query my db to provide me the following output:

```
user_id     user_name     status
0000000     user1         enrolled
1234567     user2         active
9999999     user3         deactived
```

instead of giving me values 0, 1, and 3?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, s.acct_status_desc status 
FROM usertbl u, accountstatustbl s
WHERE u.acct_status = s.acct_status
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Sorry, I used the reserved "as" in my query. Now it is fixed.

Comment: thank you for the correction, and the new sql statement is now working!^_^

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
SELECT user.user_id, user.user_name, status.description
FROM usertbl user left outer join accountstatustbl status
on user.acct_status=status.acct_status
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `INNER JOIN` assuming that `acct_status` in `usertbl` has no `NULL` values:

```
SELECT a.user_id, 
       a.user_name, 
       b.status_desc AS status 
FROM   usertbl a 
       INNER JOIN accountstatustbl b 
               ON b.acct_status = a.acct_status
```

you can also read about [MySQL JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to understand more about `joins`